# Pressing multiple modifier keys using AutoHotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

This should be pretty easy to do, but I can't figure it out. To open a link in a new tab and switch to it in Chrome, you press ctrl+shift and click. I want a button on my mouse to map to ctrl+shift. I tried the following, none of them work:

```
XButton1::+^
XButton1::+ctrl
XButton1::^shift
XButton1::SendInput, {shift}{ctrl}
XButton1::Send, {shift}{ctrl}
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
XButton1:: Send {XButton1} ; If you remove this line, XButton1 loses its native function

XButton1 & LButton::                    ;  XButton1 becomes a prefix key
    If WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")  ; open a link in a new tab:
        Send, {Shift Down}{Ctrl Down}{LButton Down}{LButton Up}{Ctrl Up}{Shift Up}
    ; If WinActive("ahk_exe notepad.exe")
        ; do sth
    ; If WinActive...
        ; do sth else   
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo

Comment: With this code, I have to let go of XButton1 before the link opens. Do you know how to make it so that I don't have to let go?

Comment: Actually, I just forgot to reload the script. This doesn't seem to do anything at all, even if I remove the `If WinActive("ahk_exe chrome.exe")` line.

Comment: I edited my answer. Try it again.

Comment: I got it working by changing `KeyWait, XButton1` to `KeyWait, LButton` in your original script. Thanks!